# can't able to return pointer value of function to main

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

link of program question https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-sticks/problem

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* readline();
char** split_string(char*);

 int* cutTheSticks(int arr_count, int* arr, int* result_count) {
int c=arr_count,min;
int result[c];
for (int k=0;k<arr_count;k++){
    min = *arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    if (*(arr + i) < min)
      min = *(arr + i);
    }
    int count=0;
    for (int i=0; i < c; i++) {
        if(min==*(arr+i))count++;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < c; i++) {
        *(arr+i)=*(arr+i)-min;
    }
    int temp=0;
    for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
        for(int x=i;x<c;x++){
            if(*(arr+i)<*(arr+x)){
                temp=*(arr+i);
                *(arr+i)=*(arr+x);
                *(arr+x)=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    result[k]= c;
        *(result_count)=*(result_count)+1;
    c = c - count;
    if(c==0)break;
}
return result;
 }

int main()
 {
FILE* fptr = fopen(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"), "w");

char* n_endptr;
char* n_str = readline();
int n = strtol(n_str, &n_endptr, 10);

if (n_endptr == n_str || *n_endptr != '\0') { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

char** arr_temp = split_string(readline());

int* arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    char* arr_item_endptr;
    char* arr_item_str = *(arr_temp + i);
    int arr_item = strtol(arr_item_str, &arr_item_endptr, 10);

    if (arr_item_endptr == arr_item_str || *arr_item_endptr != '\0') { 
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    *(arr + i) = arr_item;
}

int arr_count = n;

int result_count;
int* result = cutTheSticks(arr_count, arr, &result_count);

for (int i = 0; i < result_count; i++) {
    fprintf(fptr, "%d", *(result + i));

    if (i != result_count - 1) {
        fprintf(fptr, "\n");
    }
}

fprintf(fptr, "\n");

fclose(fptr);

return 0;
}

char* readline() {
size_t alloc_length = 1024;
size_t data_length = 0;
char* data = malloc(alloc_length);

while (true) {
    char* cursor = data + data_length;
    char* line = fgets(cursor, alloc_length - data_length, stdin);

    if (!line) { break; }

    data_length += strlen(cursor);

    if (data_length < alloc_length - 1 || data[data_length - 1] == '\n') { 
    break; }

    size_t new_length = alloc_length << 1;
    data = realloc(data, new_length);

    if (!data) { break; }

    alloc_length = new_length;
}

if (data[data_length - 1] == '\n') {
    data[data_length - 1] = '\0';
}

data = realloc(data, data_length);

return data;
}

char** split_string(char* str) {
char** splits = NULL;
char* token = strtok(str, " ");

int spaces = 0;

while (token) {
    splits = realloc(splits, sizeof(char*) * ++spaces);
    if (!splits) {
        return splits;
    }

    splits[spaces - 1] = token;

    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}

return splits;
}
```

This above code is my full code from harkerrank, below is main fuction.
    i can't able to return my pointer value from cutTheStricks to main function.

> ```
> // Please store the size of the integer array to be returned in
>     result_count 
>     pointer. For example,
> // int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
> //
> // *result_count = 3;
> //
> // return a;
> ```

```
int* cutTheSticks(int arr_count, int* arr, int* result_count) {
int c=arr_count,min;
int result[c];
for (int k=0;k<arr_count;k++){
    min = *arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    if (*(arr + i) < min)
      min = *(arr + i);
    }
    int count=0;
    for (int i=0; i < c; i++) {
        if(min==*(arr+i))count++;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < c; i++) {
        *(arr+i)=*(arr+i)-min;
    }
    int temp=0;
    for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
        for(int x=i;x<c;x++){
            if(*(arr+i)<*(arr+x)){
                temp=*(arr+i);
                *(arr+i)=*(arr+x);
                *(arr+x)=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    result[k]= c;
        *(result_count)=*(result_count)+1;
    c = c - count;
    if(c==0)break;
}
return result;
```

}

I am not getting any output but my logic is correct.
I know there is there is something missing therefore i can't able to return my output;
I can't figure out which pointer value(*result or *result_count ) is not passing 
or what is happening i can't able to figure out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, please make sure the code is a [mcve], that it is consistently formatted and that your error description contains the actual observations.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the address of a local array whose life time ends with the function, change

```
int result[c];
```

to

```
int *result = malloc(sizeof(*result) * c);
```

You are also using the address of an uninitialized value here:

```
*(result_count)=*(result_count)+1;
```

change

```
int result_count;
```

to

```
int result_count = 0;
```

Comment: still same problem.no output

Comment: there is one problem occuring when i am changing *(result_count)=*(result_count)+1; to  *(result_count)++;

Comment: Yes, you are using this value uninitialized, you have an edit.

Comment: You are welcome, another suggestion: do not reuse the same address with `realloc` since it can fail, use a temporary pointer.

Comment: what is difference between  "sizeof(*result) * c" and "sizeof(int)*c".

Comment: There is no difference, but the first one allows you to change the type i.e. to `long int` without changing the type in the call to `malloc`, always prefer the first option.

Comment: i have one more same problem,can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610909/segmentation-fault-in-complex-input

Comment: @SatyamskillzIN, I don't see any problem with this code, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)